# Force intellij to regenerate .iml files for a maven project with multiple modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module, config

I'm working with a maven project composed of multiple modules. Currently apart from the parent module, all the other modules don't have a .iml file. This cause problems each time I close and reopen intellij as 
I have to reimport (with maven) the whole Project for intellij to work properly again. Otherwise I don't have any code completion, Intellij can't resolve dependancies and so on.

I tried to reimport each submodules as well as reimporting the whole project from scratch but it didn't make Intellij to regenerate the .iml files.

Is there a way to force Intellij to regenerate .iml files ?

I'm working with intellij idea: 2019.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.6817.14, built on September 24, 2019

[Intellij Maven import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdhb6.png)

Comment: Sounds like your project has issues...

Comment: Please attach screenshot from "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing". Where are your modules located? Isn't it a network or cloud folder?

Comment: I've added the screenshot. And all the modules are stored on my local disk.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project? Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue?

Comment: If I create a new sample project, Intellij correctly creates .iml files. And I've checked inside the logs I have nothing apart warnings when intellij doesn't find .iml files when I open it: `WARN - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - File C:\Users\myname\IdeaProjects\my-project\project-ui\project-ui.iml does not exist `

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I don't have such a serious issue, for me it shows up as more of an annoyance.

Comment: @Ungeheuer I resolved this by creating manually the missing .iml files. I believe my problem is due to the fact that's a GIT project and at some point the .iml files were in GIT but then someone added them in the .gitignore and it ended up creating conflicts. Afterward this problem occured with Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and was not able to find any way for IntelliJ to regenerate the files. It seems to be due to such files being added on .gitignore - seems IntelliJ won't create it then, at least in some use cases.

However, *.iml files are really simple and it it easy enough to copy from some working module and edit it if needed. For my case, just copying and renaming correctly was enough.

Deleting and recreating the workspace would've probably also worked.